# Do tides occur on planets like Neptune, having water?

Tags: neptune, tidal-forces

I mean, we experience tides here on earth because of combined effect of gravitational field of moon and sun. So I thought that tides could also occur on other planets.

*Let us consider Neptune where the gas transits into a slushy ice and water layer. The water-ammonia ocean serves as the planet's mantle, and contains more than ten times the mass of Earth. Also it has **14**  moons. What I was thinking was that more moons would mean more tidal effect would be seen even if distance from sun has increased.*

But then I thought that the moons of Neptune would all have different orbits and different time periods of rotation. So this will definitely impact the extent of tides.

-To what extent will this affect tides?

- And how will tides formed on Neptune be different than that  formed on earth? I mean, how will they vary in properties?